# Gap between image and text

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this page, and as you can see on the second "entry", there is a gap between the H2 and the image, but not the others.

Webpage: http://sim.rgmgleague.com/cap/trades.php

[image: problem]

I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Thank you all, needing the float on .teambanner did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `float:right` to the class `.teambanner` and remove the bottom margin

```
.teambanner {
    /* margin-bottom: 70px; */
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add css

```
.teambanner{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

**OR**

```
.teambanner{
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
.team_1_h2 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.team_2_h2 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.team_2_logo {
    /* float: right; comment this float out!*/
    height: 40px;
}
```